# Cannot shift between multiple panels on Designer View?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a desktop application with a dashboard in it. Now there are multiple panels on the form which contains different controls e.g.

***NewCustomerPanel***, contains Controls for adding Customer

***SearchPanel***, Contains Controls to search a Customer

and there are other different forms on each other. When I run the application all the panels work fine but on designer view I cannot switch between different panels.

**Example:** The recent panel I included was of ***SettingPanel*** and before this was ***SearchPanel***, so now I want to open the ***NewCustomerPanel*** but can't do so. the panels keep on shifting between ***SearchPanel*** and ***SettingsPanel***

**Note:** There are Similar questions on stackoverflow but solution to them is ***Sent to Back*** and ***Bring to Front***

[image]

but the problem stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Properties window for your form and use the dropdown list (circled in red on my image below) and select the panel you want to view/edit.

[image]